# What is Bran doing in S08E03?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

What is Bran/Three-Eyed Raven doing in *Game of Thrones* S08E03 when he goes into GreenSight?

Is he spying on the Night King or is he providing insights into the battle or is he searching for some key information which he has to communicate to the rest of the cast?

Could Bran have communicated with Arya for her to jump on the Night King? 
Because Bran was surrounded by wights and White Walkers, there is no way Arya could have got past so many of them considering the fact she had a tough time with 10 of them at the library scene 10 mins prior.

Comment: Related: [What was the point of Bran warging into the ravens during S8E3?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211103/98028) on SFF.

Comment: He tells Theon, "I am going to go now." , Go where?

Comment: I thought there was some missing information to solve the puzzle. Because they hyped the Night King for 8 seasons and killed him in 20 mins. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Related: [How did Arya manage the sneak attack?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99855/49) But let's give it a little time for now before we condense every other *GoT* question asked today into Bran's warging. ;-)

Comment: Look we know that Arya has abilities of the faceless men and that Faceless Men have certain skills to possibly metaphysical abilities. In 8.01 Jon comments on how Arya snuck up on him and Arya asks how could of he survived a wound to the heart and he says, he didn't. This is an acknowledgement that they have used magic to survive without really understanding the magic they use. So there may be a few ways Arya could of done it, but some credit has be given to Melisandre because she "triggered" something that made Arya understand her role in this situation.

Comment: As for Bran we see him morph into a bunch of crows and seemingly he is looking for TNK to lure him back. I'm just hoping we're not really done with NK king yet, because I feel like too much of the fantasy genre was defused for the story's own good. Would Martin really go through this trouble to throw almost all of it out the window?

Comment: @FirstSlack: It might make sense if you consider that only 3 episodes are left, with much plot to resolve.

Answer (score 8):

He probably is keeping an eye on the battle, sure. For one, to prepare himself, if he can, for when the Night King comes to him. Also, I'm sure anyone, anywhere, on that night would like to have known what was going on.  He's sitting there, waiting for the ghouls to arrive, as the only one who can see what's going on elsewhere..... does he really have anything else to do?

As far as your contention that Arya couldn't have gotten past the dead, based on what happened in the library - she couldn't have fought her way through all of them, but (A) when she had her weapon, she easily killed dozens on the top of the wall, but in-close fighting with a mob of them for any length of time is a losing proposition for anyone, as Beric (and thousands of others) showed.

(B) But what the library DID show us is that she was able to make it from one end to the other, only feet or inches away from them, and even when they specifically looked where she was hiding just seconds before, she was gone, without a trace.  If they don't already see her, in the open, she's very difficult to spot or track, apparently, as a faceless assassin might be expected to be.

I'm not sure how that demonstration of stealth where she actually gets past all the wights in the library and out the other end, matches up with your contention that it showed she would not have been able to get past the dead, especially with the Night King's focus so squarely on Bran.

Comment: There is a brief cut of a Walker looking over their shoulder (just before Arya jumps the NK). If you look at it closely, you see that the Walker's hair is moved by the wind, and that's what catches his attention. This intentionally suggests that Arya was so quiet (and fast) that only the draft from her running past the Walkers gave her away.

Comment: @Flater - agreed.